# Getting org.springframework.orm.ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException in spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have created a function which is trying to save something in DB where version is enabled hence it can give optimistic lock exception. I catch the exception and try it again after fetching from DB. I am also using @transactional annotation to start a new transaction everytime. But I get org.springframework.orm.ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException even before my save function is called.

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void handleExecution(@NonNull final Execution execution, final Map<String, Object> data, final String pattern) {

    log.info("Processing notification pattern {} with data {} for execution {}",pattern,data,execution);

    if (ExecutionStatus.PROCESSING.equals(execution.getStatus()) || ExecutionStatus.WAITING.equals(execution.getStatus())) {
        //Put the received notification in the execution queue

        List<Map<String, Object>> notificationQueue = execution.getNotificationQueue();
        Map<String,Object> notificationMap = new HashMap<>();
        notificationMap.put(pattern, data);
        notificationQueue.add(notificationMap);
        execution.setNotificationQueue(notificationQueue);

        try
        {
            executionBuilder.save(execution);
        }
        catch(OptimisticLockingFailureException e)
        {
            log.error("Save of execution {} failed due to optimistic locking, retrying",execution);
            //Fetch the object again and call again
            Optional<Execution> savedExecution = executionBuilder.findOne(execution.getId());
            if(savedExecution.isPresent())
            {
                handleExecution(savedExecution.get(),data, pattern);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The detailed exception which I get is:

```
2018-07-11 08:09:39.408  INFO 8251 --- [thread_pool_executor-45] 
o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of 

batch it still contained JDBC statements
2018-07-11 08:09:39.408 ERROR 8251 --- [thread_pool_executor-45] reactor.bus.EventBus                     : Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1

org.springframework.orm.ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:320) ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244) ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:521) ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761) ~[spring-tx-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730) ~[spring-tx-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:504) ~[spring-tx-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:292) ~[spring-tx-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656) ~[spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at com.gor.platform.process.support.service.builder.ExecutionBuilderImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a036b2e6.patch(<generated>) ~[process-service-2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at com.gor.platform.process.support.service.event.receiver.ProcessEventReceiver.accept(ProcessEventReceiver.java:58) ~[process-service-2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at com.gor.platform.process.support.service.event.receiver.ProcessEventReceiver.accept(ProcessEventReceiver.java:23) ~[process-service-2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at reactor.bus.EventBus$3.accept(EventBus.java:317) ~[reactor-bus-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at reactor.bus.EventBus$3.accept(EventBus.java:310) ~[reactor-bus-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at reactor.bus.routing.ConsumerFilteringRouter.route(ConsumerFilteringRouter.java:72) ~[reactor-bus-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at reactor.bus.EventBus.accept(EventBus.java:591) [reactor-bus-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at reactor.bus.EventBus.accept(EventBus.java:63) [reactor-bus-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at reactor.core.dispatch.AbstractLifecycleDispatcher.route(AbstractLifecycleDispatcher.java:160) [reactor-core-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at reactor.core.dispatch.MultiThreadDispatcher$MultiThreadTask.run(MultiThreadDispatcher.java:74) [reactor-core-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_171]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_171]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_171]
Caused by: org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.checkBatched(Expectations.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.verifyOutcome(Expectations.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:46) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3082) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2961) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3341) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:145) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:582) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:456) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1282) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:465) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2963) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2339) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:485) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
```

The executionBuilder.save internally calls dao.save which is not seen in the stack trace. Why is this exception getting thrown even before the save is called. When save is called then the exception is caught and things work fine. But occasionally this exception is thrown without the save and hence doesn't get caught.

My gut feeling says it has something to do with @Transactional.

For the information my application is multithreaded and many thread might modify the same data at the same time.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It happens because Hibernate is trying to flush the session because as far as it’s concerned the transaction is successful after your method completes the first time. You should rollback the transaction before attempting again.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that for the first time I should get my log printed in the catch block and since I am catching this exception how does it get thrown to the caller of handleExecution function?

Comment: No you’re seeing it later because Hibernate is not flushing when your dao save is called. It’s flushing after your method is finished and Hibernate wants to commit the transaction. You can call an entity manager flush in your dao to get the error straight away.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I think I got the issue. Since I am using CrudRepository as my Dao hence I would not be able to add flush in it. Should I do a flush after executionBuilder.save(execution) inside try/catch block manually like below:  try
            {
                Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
                executionBuilder.save(execution);
                session.flush();
            }............Any reason why it doesn't occur everytime since most of the time exception gets caught in my code?

Comment: Any reason why it doesn't occur everytime since most of the time exception gets caught in my code? I think the reason is that when dao.save it self gets this error because the version doesn't match then my application catches it. But if dao.save is successful but since its not committed as yet hence at flush when it actually does commit and the version has changed till that time then it throws it to the caller

Comment: are you getting every time error on a single update on the database or multiple updates at a time?

Answer (score 4):

you can handle optimistic lock using spring retry option inside the controller.
Download for this class

```
import org.springframework.retry.annotation.Retryable;
```

For Example

```
@RequestMapping(value = CommonConstants.DETAILS_ADD_OR_UPDATE, method = RequestMethod.POST)
@Retryable(value = { StaleObjectStateException.class,
        HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException.class }, maxAttempts = 1, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 5000))
public ResponseJson addOrUpdate(@RequestBody User user, HttpServletRequest request) {
    try{
    responseJson.setResponse(adminService.update(userId, user));
    }
    catch (DataIntegrityViolationException | ConstraintViolationException e) {
        ErrorInfo errorInfo = errorCodeHelper.getErrorInfo(CommonConstants.E1071_ERROR_CODE,
                CommonConstants.E1071_ERROR_DESCRIPTION);
        throw new ServiceException(errorInfo);
    }
    return responseJson;
}
```

---

This is the important one add on the top of the method

```
@Retryable(value = { StaleObjectStateException.class,
        HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException.class }, maxAttempts = 1, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 5000))
```

Comment: I used `@Retryable` on top of my method but it is never retried..Used `@enableRetry` on my app config and also tried `@recover` method to see if it is getting caught but it was never called. Exception is always throws out. Just to add my method is not there in controller

Comment: Yes, you right we have to unable inside configuration class @EnableRetry

Comment: It didn't work even with all that annotations in place. It was never retrying. I even write recover to check if it ever called. But it was never called. The problem isn't solved.

Answer (score 1):

> **ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException *occurs after transaction is completed.***

If you are looking for 1 or 2 retries:
In controller you can handle else you have follow what faizakram has given:

```
    try {
        service.method_name(requestObj);
    } catch (ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException e) {
        try {
            service.method_name(requestObj);
        } catch (ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException oex) {
            //throw error here
        }
    }
```

In service:

```
method_name() throws ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException{
//business loginc
}
```